# the way to update a list of dom item with java script?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am the all in one developer of [this site](http://www.bunch-it.com). In that site if you click on any node on graph it updates the content of the result div. I am doing it in idiotic way that I just rewrite all the div content from scratch. I am sure that it is not the best way so what would you suggest for that kind of dynamic update?

I think that there would be a way matching results (maybe their id) and the resultls' div's id so that I can keep all these snippet divs in a array with these ids. Then when I need update, I just rewite all the content again but just pushing the dom objects that are matching the results.

Is it also possible to keep the dom objects in div and push on them to the body of the page when they are needed?

Or any other way for succeed it?

Comment: The code should be here. not in same link.

Answer (score 1):

Simply hide the divs that do not match the clicked node in the graph. This way when they click on reset you show all the divs, no need to keep recreating the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the divs inside your document and hide them initially. Keep all div ids for individual node in an array or maybe some kind of object.

When a node is clicked, insert those divs corresponding to the clicked node to the target div and set them visible.

One problem with this approach is: even the hidden divs are part of the DOM tree, when you insert the chosen divs to the target div, those divs are in fact moved from the original DOM nodes to the new nodes. This way, when the user click the same node again, those divs are no longer there.

One way to solve this problem is by cloning the nodes first and move the cloned ones to the target place or you may better put them back first to avoid dangling nodes before update the target with new divs.